how to stop Particles from moving after landing the ground
I created a scene where leaves falling on the ground with wind.
without wind, the leaves can stay still on the ground.
for ground: physics > collision > damping
with wind, leaves will keep moving on the ground.


it there a way to stop particles from moving once landing on the ground? thanks in advance.

Generally speaking: What did you expect? In reality, leaves keep moving with wind too, unless the ground is wet and they stick to it. Or if they are stuck in grass more tightly then the wind blows to get them out, but your ground is perfectly flat and smooth. But also in reality, wind does not always blow constantly with the same strength. Did you animate the wind properties? Another thing is, directly above the ground the wind has less effect than higher up.
Now what you can do this either enable Kill Particles on the collision object (the ground) or Die on Hit under Physics > Deflection in the Particles Properties. Additionally I have to say that from my own experience other things which do not kill the particles like damping, stickiness, friction etc. do not yield satisfactory results in my opinion (especially when they are not consistent).
No matter which of the two "killing" methods you choose, in both cases you have to enable Dead under Render > Extra in the Particles Properties or otherwise they will disappear after hitting the ground. Unfortunately they will "die" immediately when touching the ground, no sliding around on the floor before they come to a halt.
The difference of either setting the collision to kill the particles or instead setting the particles to die on hit is, changing the setting of the particles lets them die on all collision objects, while enabling it on the collision objects lets them bounce of other collision objects without dying.
For example, if you have a ground and a tree trunk in the scene, both collision objects. If you do not want the particles to stick on the tree but on the ground, then do not enable Die on Hit for the particles. Instead enable Kill Particles for the ground, but not the tree.
Collision object settings:

Particles Properties:

